# Link to line in code snippet

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

When sharing code from GitHub with people, I can get a link to the exact line, which helps with clarity when I'm bringing attention to something specific.

I would like to do the same when linking people to code blocks in Stack Overflow answers. Sometimes, there's something specific in an answer that I want to bring attention to, maybe not the answer's entire code block. Is this something on the roadmap to be supported by Stack Overflow?

Comment: I've also posted to [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342938/link-to-line-in-code-snippet) in case this more broadly affects other sites.

Comment: Another way to handle that would be for code blocks to have toggleable line numbers, like most code editors have. That might be easier to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the argument against line numbers I've seen refer to the fact that answers can change, therefore invalidates previous references. But in the moment sharing could benefit from just having line numbers to say "Check out the answer's first code block line 12" (but this doesn't negate the problems).

Comment: Quite frankly, I haven't really come across situations where I've missed linkable lines. Code snippets shouldn't be *that* long to begin with. It would be better to quote relevant code in answers, so it's all right inline, and you don't have to jump back and forth between code and explanation. The only use may be in comments, but it's often entirely feasible to quote a short or abbreviated snippet to establish context.

Comment: @deceze Fair enough, and that's what I usually do anyway. :)

Comment: Cross posting was never a good idea.

Comment: Ok. I went off an initial comment from the original post and planned to remove it, then a later comment said it was relevant to everything. Should I delete this now or not @PeterMortensen?